# Batch: determine if a substring exist in a line read from a file

Tags: string, file-io, batch-file, substring

I am brand new to batch.
My intention is writing a batch that read every line from a file, and depends on the line read in do some different tasks.  Here is some sample

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do ( 
  echo %%a
  *if %%a contains abc do (other tasks)*           
)
```

In addition, can I detect a "newline" in batch??
if the test.txt looks like:

```
123
345
abckdla

abd
abd
abc

test
```

can I print "this is a new line" when the for loop is at row4 and row8 of test.txt??

Great thanks to your time.

Answer (score 6):

There are two questions in your post

1.- Checking if a variable contains a substring.

try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do ( 
  set tst=%%a
  set tst=!tst:ab=!
  if not !tst!==%%a ( 
    echo %%a contains ab
  ) else (
    echo %%a does not contain ab
  )
)
```

see `HELP SET` for more detailed information.

2.- the FOR command skips blank lines. Try `HELP FOR` and read "Blank lines are skipped".
There are convoluted solutions involving for example `TYPE` and `FIND` I would try to avoid unless strictly necessary.